# MacVim doesn't display on El Capitan

Tags: macvim, osx-el-capitan

I just upgraded to El Capitan installed MacVim 7.3. When I start it there is no display just the menu bar. Is there some magic incantation I need to perform?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with MacVim 7.3 (snapshot 66).

I fixed the problem by downloading and installing the latest binary release from [macvim-dev.github.io/macvim](https://macvim-dev.github.io/macvim/) (MacVim 7.4 snapshot 99).